# How to Show Subcategory under Specific Category in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

I have some issue with my code, the Same Subcategory is showing under all Category, if a category doesn't have sub category then that category is also showing subcategory, I want to show if a category has subcategory then it should be shown in dropdown otherwise it should be blank.

here is my models.py file...

```
class WebCategory(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name='Category name')
  slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='Slug')
  title = models.CharField(max_length=165, null=True)
  metadesc = models.TextField(max_length=165, null=True)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  class Meta:
      verbose_name_plural = 'WebCategory'

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.name)
    super(WebCategory, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

 def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class WebSubCategory(models.Model):
  category = models.ForeignKey('WebCategory', related_name='subcategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,
                             null=True, verbose_name='Select category')
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
  metadesc = models.TextField(max_length=165, null=True)
  description = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  class Meta:
      verbose_name_plural = 'WebSubCategory'

  def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

Here is my views.py file

```
def home(request):                                                                  
  context = RequestContext(request)                                               
  category_list = WebCategory.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:5]                 
  subcategory_list = WebSubCategory.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:5]           
  context_dict = {'webcat': category_list, 'websubcat':subcategory_list}          
  return render_to_response('home.html', context_dict, context)
```

And here is my header.html file..

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="mainNav">
     {%if webcat %}
     {% for category in webcat %}
        <li class="dropdown dropdown-mega">
            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="JavaScript:void()">
                {{category}}
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                {% if websubcat %}
                <li>
                    <div class="dropdown-mega-content">
                        <div class="row">
                            {% for subcategory in websubcat.all %}
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <span class="dropdown-mega-sub-title">Elements 1</span>
                                <ul class="dropdown-mega-sub-nav">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{{subcategory.slug}}">{{subcategory.name}}</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                {% else %}
                <p>No category Found</p>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
 {% else %}
<p>No Category Found</p>
{% endif %}
```

Please guide me how i can show specific subcategory (if a category have subcategory) under category, right now i am getting subcategory under all category.

Comment: Your view function seems to be "cut off" here (after a certain number of characters per line).

Comment: Changed views function now

Comment: Can you show me the WebCategory and WebSubCategory models. Looks like you are not running the for loop in the template following the relationship.

Comment: I have updated my models, Please check once..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's showing you the same ones because that's what you're asking it to do; you always iterate over the same set.

Instead of sending WebSubCategory from the view, you should follow the relationship in the template. You haven't shown the models so I don't know exactly what the field names are, but for example:

```
{% for subcategory in category.subcategory.all|slice:":5" %}
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <span class="dropdown-mega-sub-title">Elements 1</span>
    <ul class="dropdown-mega-sub-nav">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{{subcategory.slug}}">{{subcategory.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Also note, you shouldn't be using RequestContext and `render_to_response` in your view; use the `render` shortcut instead.

```
def home(request):                                                                  
  category_list = WebCategory.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:5]                 
  context_dict = {'webcat': category_list}
  return render(request ,'home.html', context_dict)
```

Comment: Updated; although note that `subcategory` is not a good related_name, since it actually relates to *multiple* subcategories.

Comment: So what should I change the `subcategory`  relaed_name, can u please write the complete query...

Comment: Well what I showed you will work, I was just making a stylistic point; if you insist on setting it at all (which I don't recommend) you should use `subcategories`.

Comment: you mean it should be something like this related_name='subcategories'

Comment: I have updated my code with your answer but still, it's showing no category found error.

Comment: It's working now, You save my day...Thank You Daniel

Comment: Hi Daniel, After showing subcategories my path is showing something like this..
http://127.0.0.1:8000/%5E(%3FPgst-registration-requirements.+)/$

here is my urls.py file...
 `path(r'^(?P<slug>.+)/$', views.show_page, name="show_page"),`

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with this code, you should have asked a new question. But it seems like you are mixing up path and re_path (regex) syntaxes.

Comment: My code is something like this...
 `urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"^$", views.home, name="home"),
    re_path(r"blog/$", views.blog, name="blog"),
    url(r"^(?P<pk>\d+)/$", views.show_blog, name="show_blog"),
    path(r'^(?P<slug>.+)/$', views.show_page, name="show_page"),`

Comment: Like I said, you're mixing up `path` and `re_path` (as well as `url` for some reason), but like I also said, you should ask a new question.